# Drop Down populated by mysql selection not posting

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to PHP here and struggling with an issue.  I've created a form to submit information to a powershell script on the back end.  I have one drop down field (telephone) that is pulling from mysql and populating.  That part is working great.  The issue that I am having is that when i go to post the data and pass it to the powershell script that field (telephone) is being passed as blank.  I'm not sure where I may have caused the issue and looking for some help here.

Here is what I have.  I'd like to keep it in PHP if possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<?php



// If there was no submit variable passed to the script (i.e. user has visited the page without clicking submit), display the form:
if(!isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
?>

<form name="testForm" id="testForm" action="BTAM2.php" method="post" /> <br />

First Name: <input type="text" name="SAMname" id="SAMname" maxlength="20" /><br />         <br/>
Telephone Number: 

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","it");
//============== check connection
if(mysqli_errno($con))
{
echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
}



//This creates the drop down box

echo "<select name='phonenum' id='phonenum'>";
echo '<option value="0">'.' '.'</option>';
$query = mysqli_query($con,"Select `btphonenumber` from `btphone` where `btuser` = ' '");
$query_display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM btphone");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "<option value='". $row['id']."'>".$row['btphonenumber']
```

.'';

```
}

echo '</select>';


?><br /> <br />




<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create User" />
</form>
<?php   
}
// Else if submit was pressed, check if all of the required variables have a value:
elseif((isset($_POST["submit"])) && (!empty($_POST["SAMname"])))
{
// Get the variables submitted by POST in order to pass them to the PowerShell script:
$firstname = $_POST["SAMname"];
$telenumber = $_POST["phonenum"];




var_dump($_REQUEST);


}
// Else the user hit submit without all required fields being filled out:
```

else
    {
    echo "Sorry, you did not complete all required fields. Please go back and try again.";
    }
    ?>

Comment: You have an space between name= 'phonenum'. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @chepe263 white space in html tags is irrelevant.  Try doing `var_dump($_POST)` in the `elseif` block and see if the variables that are being posted to the page.  Also remove the `/` from the `<form ... >` tag because this is not a self closing tag it is closed by `</form>`

Comment: Check the html that is output and make sure the value attributes for the `option` tags of telephone `select` are being populated with the ids that you get from the database

Comment: Okay I removed the / as suggested from the <form ...>.  The var_dump showed ["phonenum"]=>string(0) "".

Comment: Please, read the [minimal example guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't need to see 3 text inputs, 3 dropdowns and 5 checkboxes to diagnose the problem. Creating this example also *helps you* to solve the problem alone. All in all, it's a nice troubleshooting technique.

Comment: I've updated the code to the minimal guide.  I understand breaking things down to simplify the issue, still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my own issue.  in the line

```
echo "<option value='". $row['id']."'>".$row['btphonenumber']
```

I should have had

```
echo "<option value='". $row['btphonenumber']."'>".$row['btphonenumber']
```